# What is the name of the tactic that politicians use to bury people with torrent of words?

Tags: terminology

Some people write bloated books and long essays with skilful use of hooks, e.g. Jared Diamond; some others speak in long-drawn sentences with torrents of words, e.g. Noam Chomsky. It reminds me of a tactic politicians use to waste people's time. I came across this word before but I can't retrieve it from either memory or the internet.

Comment: This might be better on english.stackexchange.com, since it's more of a vocabulary question...  or at least you're more likely to get an answer there.

Comment: Good idea. It is also likely that this word has not made it to the dictionary yet.

Comment: Since when is verbosity a means of rhetorical dishonesty?

Comment: @Avi, your reply is irrelevant. please read the question carefully.

Comment: @GeorgeChen Don't patronize me please. I read your question, but I'm not sure I understand it.

Wait. Filibuster?

Comment: Filibuster is very close, but I'm pretty sure that is not it.

Comment: Question has been re-asked [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160126/what-is-the-name-of-the-tactic-that-politicians-use-to-bury-people-with-torrent).  Voting to close this one.

Comment: Answer from the other question is [bloviate](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=bloviate&searchmode=none), which I don't think I've ever run across before.

Comment: I settle for bloviate for now. My last impression is this technique was widely recognized during campaign seasons.

Comment: @GeorgeChen - Apparently it was just a passing fad in 2000, rather than sticking around.  But at the time it may have been more known.

Comment: There is some sort of insult to Chomsky and Jared Diamond here. That is too funny!

Comment: @Razie, read Bertrand Russell, then you will feel what I feel.

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom - Chomsky definitely bloviated, but I do not know whether he is a crook or not because I never had the patience to finish any of his books. Diamond is a bloviating crook; I read several of his books from back to back and was infuriated by his skilful use of hooks and suspense. I think we need to coin a new word "chomskydiamond" as the transitive counterpart bloviate. E.g, he stood there and chomskydiamonded the public.

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom: How about "chomvelicovskydiamond"? There is a poetic quality in it.  "His book chomvelicovskydiamonded the public, but somehow won the 1998 Pulitzer prize for general non-fiction."

Comment: Or "marx-tegmark-chom-velicovsky-diamond" I hope someday people will use it without the hyphens.

Comment: "Do not send your kids to school, or they will get tegmark-marx-chom-velicovsky-pinker-diamonded." not much of a tongue twister.

Comment: Make no mistake, I wouldn't call them evil. They just belong to that class of men who desperately want to look intellectual.

Comment: It used to be my passion to dislodge writers like these one by one. I can hit Marx where it hurts, and I think we are even now. Diamond is swiftly swept aside - no much of a fight really. Then I began to notice this bloviating technique whose sole purpose is to consume the readers waking hours ... Nevertheless, I am careful not to make far reaching conclusions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## **bloviate**

> verb
> informal
>
> talk at length, esp. in an inflated or empty way.

*Kudos to [bib](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/23491/bib) on the [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/160126/61375) stack exchange.

Comment: I can't believe someone mentioned "bloviate" on a politics related website and Bill O'Reilley's shadow didn't make an appearance

Comment: Sorry, I don't watch TV.

Answer (score 4):

[Obfuscation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation) may be the word you are looking for.  It implies that a thing is being presented, but not necessarily in the most clear manner, often with the intent of deception on key details. That said, this may not be strictly political.

Comment: Maybe but I'm not sure. Obfuscation is aimed to make obscure. The word I'm searching for is aimed to consume people's waking hours.

Comment: @GeorgeChen This is literally what you would do if you wanted to waste someones time. Unless you mean something more like talking over someone else, like on TV?

Answer (score 4):

Somewhat related is the Gish gallop https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gish_gallop where you do an  'argument dump' to overwhelm your opponent.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit of a long shot, but:

> It reminds me of a tactic politicians use to waste people's time.

This makes me think you're referring to the [filibuster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filibuster). The filibuster is a procedural tool in which a politician will just keep talking and talking in order to prolong debate and prevent the bill from coming to a vote.

Nowadays though, in the US Senate, you don't need to actually talk to filibuster. The procedural filibuster allows politicians to just announce that they are going to filibuster, at which point it takes a super-majority of votes to override the filibuster. However, a recent [rules change](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/02/12/harry-reid-judicial-nominees_n_4776552.html) means that it only takes a normal majority of votes to override a filibuster of a non-judicial presidential nominee.

Comment: Very close. But the tactic in question is also used in blogs and news articles where hooks are skilfully used to keep people reading on and on.

Comment: What, like viral headlines and dull articles? I don't think there's a name for that, but that's not a politics question, it's an english one.

Comment: It's a political one. It aims at distraction rather than deceit.

Comment: I'm not totally sure I see the difference, and you're giving examples of its use in areas outside of politics. The English SE is _full_ of people asking if there's a word for something. I don't think this is suited to this site unless it's a technical political term.

Answer (score 2):

You may also wish to consider the word 'inundate' as in to overwhelm with information.

> The lawyers were inundated with useless credit card statements, but there was really one one charge that needed to be disclosed.

Comment: Good one. Still,there are occasions when one feels inundated but the materials that overwhelm this person are nevertheless necessary.